# gforth call C function printf with string

Tags: c, gforth

I'm calling the C function `printf` with a `S" ..."` string and I'm hitting an invalid memory address. What is the right way to pass a pointer to a null-terminated string that's been created on the Forth side to C.

Here are two versions of hello world in `gforth`, one using dedicated syntax for writing out a literal string, and the other using `type` with a string stored as a value (albeit trivially)

Here's `helloworld.fs`

```
#! /usr/bin/env gforth
.( Hello, world!)
CR
bye
```

and `helloworld2.fs`

```
#! /usr/bin/env gforth
S" Hello, world!" type
CR
bye
```

As far as I can tell, the syntax `S" Hello, world"` creates a new string in some global area inside the Forth runtime and pushes a pointer to it onto the stack. It could also be a richer object than that, I don't know whether Forth uses null-terminated strings.

In any case, `gforth` exposes some words for calling C functions, here in `hello_world_c.fs`

```
#! /usr/bin/env gforth
\c #include <stdio.h>
c-function printf- printf a -- n

S" hello" printf-
CR

bye
```

I would expect this script to print `hello` and then a newline when run. The prototype for the function `printf` is `a -- n` ... meaning it takes an address and returns something with the same size as `int`. A single format string is definitely an acceptable collection of arguments to pass to `printf`.

However, it produces the error:

```
$ ./hello_world_c.fs
ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')

in file included from *OS command line*:-1
hello_world_c.fs:5: Invalid memory address
S" hello" >>>printf-<<<
Backtrace:
$7F3A14D65018 call-c
$763A14D64F50 execute
```

I'm guessing that the problem here comes from the fact that `S" hello"` isn't really a pointer but is actually something else. Is there a way to convert it to a pointer so the call to `printf` will point to the right thing?

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out `S"` does not create a null-terminated string and does not exclusively push the address onto the stack.

`S"` creates a temporary location (that appears to live at least until the next call to `S"`) and pushes a length and address onto the stack.

After `S"` is called the length is on the top of the stack, this order is important.

Here's an example interactive session with `gforth`, with comments and a prompt (`>`) inserted for clarity.

```
$ gforth
> S" a"                  ( define a new string, push length and addr )
> .s                     ( display size of stack and contents of stack )
<2> 22565888 1
> .                      ( print and drop top item of stack ) 
1
> .s                     ( display size and contents of stack again )
<1> 22565888
bye
```

The word `s\"` is like `S"`, except that it honors C-style string escapes. It hijacks the "reader" the same way that `S"` does, but performs some translation.

Keeping all this in mind, here's an implementation of the script that calls out to `printf-` correctly.

```
#! /usr/bin/env gforth

\c #include <stdio.h>
c-function printf- printf a -- n

( synonym for drop for documentation purposes.
  remove the initial length of a length, bytes pair created by
  S" or s\" )
: drop-cstr-length drop ;

s\" hello world\n\0" drop-cstr-length
printf-

bye
```

which prints `hello world` and then exits normally.

Comment: Looking at the ANS Forth spec ( http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/ansforth-cvs/documents/html3/core/Seq.html ), shouldn't it be `\z` rather than `\0` ?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, in Forth, you would simplify this by making a new word that compiles the code you want; something like this:

```
: cstr"   postpone s\"  postpone drop ; immediate
```

Then it becomes easier to use;

```
#! /usr/bin/env gforth

\c #include <stdio.h>
c-function printf- printf a -- n

cstr" hello world\n\0" printf-
```